# Why is OpenStreetMaps in Civi 4.7.24 rendering a featureless grey map?

Tags: map

I've just upgraded a site that was running Civi 4.6.30 to 4.7.24. I use OpenStreetMaps as the Mapping provider. My maps are now appearing as featureless grey maps rather than what I'd expect.

The same seems to be true when I test it on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

My old site continues to render the map in full colour.

The template concerned (CRM/Contact/Form/Task/Map/OpenStreetMaps.tpl) certainly looks very different between the two versions of Civi that I've upgraded from/to.

Comment: This issue: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19400 - explains at least some of the rationale for recent changes to the OpenStreetMaps mapping option.

Answer (score 2):

As Graham has noted in a comment, the change in map reflects a change in [terms of use](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/tiles/) and [distribution methods](https://lists.openstreetmap.org/pipermail/talk/2016-June/076106.html) in July 2016 that necessitated the [removal of direct links](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19400) to MapQuest tiles.

- [MapQuest Issue - Direct Tile Access No Longer Supported?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/14433)
- [mapquest direct tile access discontinued](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38315300) (SO)

The plain map you are seeing is the [Carto Light](https://carto.com/location-data-services/basemaps/) basemap from Carto, which was adopted as of 4.7.19.

On our sites, we do not use the built-in maps for the public, but a [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) implementation for Drupal Views. Thus, this change only affected internal users who use the mapping, which does not occur often in our use cases. But for those who do, you can override this choice by adding a custom `OpenStreetMaps.tpl` template, with the URLs appropriate to your tile provider of choice.

[image: Carto Light All] [image: Carto Dark Nolabels]

I am not sure if any Carto tiles other than the basic light and dark (with or without labels) are licensed for this kind of use, however. The OSM wiki does provide a [list of tile servers](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) where you can explore alternatives.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Maybe I missed the men on this. Essentially what you're saying is that the CiviCRM mapping implementation using OSM data is now at best severely hobbled.

Comment: LOL, I didn't see that you'd commented on your own question. But yes, I suppose if you prefer the old MapQuest tiles, this is a downgrade. See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles for some other alternatives.

Comment: What I don't understand - yet - is why a Civi/Drupal site that I have running an older version of Civi is still able to render OSM maps perfectly well. According to the information I've read I should be seeing an alert message instead to tell me that it's all been switched off?